# Cycle2: pager only displays link to first slide and hides the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-cycle2

I'm using Cycle2 with its carousel plugin. I tried to add their pager functionality to my page, like this:

First, I created the container div:

```
<div id="concluidos-navigation" class="cycle-pager"></div>
```

Then, I set the plugin options like this:

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow"
            data-cycle-slides="> li"
            data-cycle-fx=carousel
            data-cycle-allow-wrap=false
            data-cycle-pager="#concluidos-navigation"
        >
```

The resulting HTML is this, for the first slide:

```
<span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span>
```

But for every other slide, the result is:

```
<span style="display: none;">•</span>~
```

Where does this "display: none" comes from? Am I missing something? If I inspect the element on Chrome and remove the "display: none", all links show up and work perfectly to navigate between slides.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wujrh4g1/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to fix it with a workaround by overriding the default style. First I added this to the plugin initialization:

```
data-cycle-pager-template="<strong class='cycle-pager-nav-circle'><a href=#></a></strong>"
```

And then I added a CSS rule to the "cycle-pager-nav-circle" class:

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

However, if anyone as a more clean solution, please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`hide-non-active` could be the reason perhaps. It defaults to `true`. [[Link](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/)].

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't do the job. I believe that option is for the slides themselves, not for the pager links.

Comment: @DavidMatos, can you create a simple fiddle please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wujrh4g1/). The problem occurs when I add the carousel script.